# Matplotlib - point labels built from item in a list

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib, label

Using matplotlib, I define the following function to print labels. Labels are located at the right place, but label is not correct.

```
def printPointLabel(x,y,z,iternum,ax):
    print x 
    label = '(%d, %d), ITER%s' % (x, y, iternum)
    ax.text(x, y, z, label)
```

I call printPointLabel for four different points in the for loop

```
for i,num,c in zip((0,sampl4,2*sampl4,len(simplexpath)-1),(0,sampl4,2*sampl4,len(simplexpath)),('r','r','g','b')):
    appendSimplex(xs,ys,zs,col,simplexpath[i], peaks, c)
    printPointLabel(simplexpath[i][0][0],simplexpath[i][0][1],peaks([simplexpath[i]  [0][0],simplexpath[i][0][1]]),num,ax)
```

and label content is not updated at each loop. It remains identical to first label.

Could you help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem with the

```
ax.text(x, y, z, label)
```

call. the `text` function's call signature is:

```
text(x, y, s, fontdict=None, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> sampl4 = "samp14"
>>> simplexpath = "simplexpath"
>>> zip((0,sampl4,2*sampl4,len(simplexpath)-1),(0,sampl4,2*sampl4,len(simplexpath)),('r','r','g','b'))
[(0, 0, 'r'),
 ('samp14', 'samp14', 'r'),
 ('samp14samp14', 'samp14samp14', 'g'),
 (10, 11, 'b')]
```

Did you intend `num` to be `0, samp14, 2*samp14, len(simplexpath)-1` ?

Could you give us a sample output?

Comment: Actually that last one is `len(simplexpath)`, but the point stands: that zip is weird.